# When do we need class-based views in Django?

Tags: django, python-3.x

I'm learning Django and I've finished 2 tutorials - official and amazing tutorial called Tango With Django. Though, I got everything I need to work, I have one question:

In Tango with Django aren't used class-based views -  only links to the official tutorial.

Why didn't they include this information?

When should we use class-based views and is it a good practice?

Answer (score 2):

Class based views allow you to structure your views and reuse code by harnessing inheritance and mixins.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/class-based-views/

For example you can inherit from "TemplateView" class which provides some features that you may need to use in your own view. For example you can reuse "get" method.

```
# some_app/views.py
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

class AboutView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "about.html"
```

Comment: Please add the relevant code as well as linking to the docs.  They may change or become unavailable.

Answer (score 1):

We use class based views (CBV's) to reduce the amount of code required to do repetitive tasks such as rendering a form or a template, listing the items from a queryset etc.

Using CBV's drastically reduces the amount of code required and should be used where it can be.

Answer (score 0):

It is good to be used in a CRM system. You have a a list view, item view, delete view etc, such as an blog. CBV could help you write less code.

But also because it has do too much for you. Sometimes it will be a little bit troublesome to make some customization or add some extra logic. In this situation, it is more suitable for those really experienced and familiar with CBV so that they could change it easily.